# Node.js Write and read files limits

Tags: node.js

let's say I have 300gb SSD disk with 2 v core CPU and 5gb ram

So I want to use fs nodejs to read and write and update files small ones like JSON files with 20 keys at max

How much my limits and performance? and btw I'm updating let's say static 1K files every 2 sec any limits you create.

Any story at how the performance will get and will be So sorry I'm just so concern and don't know what would happen at all

Code:

```
  const fs = require('fs');

this.AddDriver = function(ids,latitudes,longitudes){

    let driver = { 
    id: ids,
    latitude: latitudes, 
    longitude: longitudes,
    speed: 0.00,
    bearing: 0.00 
};

    let data = JSON.stringify(driver, null, 2);

    let fileID = ids+".json";

fs.writeFile("./DB/Tables/DriversData/"+fileID, data, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
//    console.log("Data written to file");
});

}
```

Comment: None of those numbers mean anything *until you benchmark it on a combination of hardware, operating system and software representative of your real-world use-case*.

Comment: I really have no idea and in the meantime, there is no way to do that litrely

Comment: That is the *only* way to tell how this will work out. The answer is somewhere between 0 and infinity otherwise.

Comment: I need an idea or theory to at least have a clue of what I'm about to do

Comment: Make a quick prototype. Test it. If you've got something that's not fast enough for your use-case we can probably advise, but saying "I need to know how fast my code is" when we have no code is not going to result in anything useful.

Comment: Like anything even if it's only a theory I need to know what I'm about to do cuz its only an idea I'm gonna use the files as a database may be funny but I need to know if it's faster than MySQL I need it for a simple thing like only latitude and longitude and id

Comment: Check question for code

Comment: That's an improvement, but what did your testing reveal? If you wrapped that in a loop and did that 10,000 times how long does it take? The `time` command is a good place to start, but there's all kinds of JavaScript performance profiling tools on NPM.

Comment: Okay I will do a loop now and do as much as I can for 10K and give you the results

Comment: As a note, a database like MySQL or Postgres will probably provide better performance with small records than thrashing around hard with individual JSON files, but you'll have to test to find out for sure. Filesystem performance varies dramatically based on the filesystem used, the storage mechanism, and other factors like IO limits imposed by a cloud provider.